# Clear task when lock task mode enabled

Tags: android

At some point in my Android app I need to clear the current task and start a new activity.

I usually do that by using [FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK) and [FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK) flags in the intent provided to Context.startActivity().

However I noticed that it doesn't work when the app is pinned (i.e [lock task mode](https://developer.android.com/work/dpc/dedicated-devices/lock-task-mode) is enabled).

Obviously I could stop lock task mode before clearing task and restart it after but it gives a bad user experience since it redisplay popups & toasts related to app pinning.

Is it somehow possible to start an activity in a clear task when lock task mode is enabled ?

Comment: I think it won't be possible. You can find code responsible for it in ActivityManagerService - [link](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/4f868ed/services/core/java/com/android/server/am/ActivityManagerService.java#4474)

Answer (score 0):

From the documentaion, there is only one way of doing this.

> If an activity previously called startLockTask(), then the activity
>   can call Activity.stopLockTask() to stop lock task mode. This method
>   only works for the activity that started lock task mode.

**OR**

You need to stop lock task by [DevicePolicyManager.setLockTaskPackages()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/admin/DevicePolicyManager#setLockTaskPackages(android.content.ComponentName,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D)) to remove the app from whitelist.

Comment: Actually I'm looking for a solution without stopping lock task mode.

Comment: I am afraid currently, there is no possible way as it was designed to for lock mode.

Answer (score 0):

Improve the business logic towards not requiring to start a new `Activity` -

because the question is: why it is even required to do so, in the given situation?

Replacing the `Fragment` in most cases suffices, unless switching the `Locale`.

---

And if only the `Activity` which started the lock-task is able to unlock it -

this still could be done by implementing an `interface`, which does just that

(obviously, I'm assuming that this `Activity` is still running).